# zabbix installation with the MySQL support

Tags: 22.04, mysql, 22.10, zabbix

I'm trying to install zabbix on my ubuntu 22.04 server.

I installed the zabbix 6.1 repository on my system.

when I try to install zabbix server with mysql support it returns the following:

```
$ sudo apt install zabbix-server-mysql zabbix-sql-scripts
Reading package lists... Done7
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 zabbix-server-mysql : Depends: libldap-2.4-2 (>= 2.4.7) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libsnmp35 (>= 5.8+dfsg) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable
 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: https://www.zabbix.com/download?zabbix=6.2&os_distribution=ubuntu&os_version=22.04&components=server_frontend_agent&db=mysql&ws=apache <- Were this the instructions you followed? if so please contact tech support.

Comment: I actually followed the "Zabbix 6 IT Infrastructure Monitoring Cookbook" Book

Comment: which eventually are the same as the URL you provided and still.. the same issue

Comment: So perhaps you should follow the official instructions instead? Very likely you added an outdated repository.